# How to close on screen keyboard from menu bar option "A" near the spotlight search

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript

I have been trying to close onscreen keyboard (Assistive control) via Terminal and AppleScript, but it restarts after getting closed for 1-2 seconds. Is there anyway to close it?

I have used scripts like these:

```
tell application "Assistive Control"

    quit

end tell
```

Please let me know how will I close it via applescript or any terminal command

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120334/discussion-on-question-by-ritesh-kumar-how-to-close-on-screen-keyboard-from-menu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update (again) per Comment**

This first *block* of *example* **AppleScript** *code* conditionally clicks the **Input** menu on the **Menu Bar** only when the **Hide Keyboard Viewer** *menu item* exists, thus hiding the **Keyboard Viewer**.

```applescript
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "TextInputMenuAgent"
        tell menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
            if menu item "Hide Keyboard Viewer" of menu 1 exists then
                set menuItemExists to true
                ignoring application responses
                    click
                end ignoring
            else
                set menuItemExists to false
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
end tell

if menuItemExists then
    do shell script "killall 'System Events'"
    tell application "System Events"
        tell application process "TextInputMenuAgent"
            tell menu 1 of menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
                click menu item "Hide Keyboard Viewer"
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end if
```

---

**Update per Comment**

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "TextInputMenuAgent"
        tell menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
            ignoring application responses
                click
            end ignoring
        end tell
    end tell
end tell

do shell script "killall 'System Events'"

tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "TextInputMenuAgent"
        tell menu 1 of menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
            click (every menu item whose name contains "Viewer")
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Note that the *example* **AppleScript** *code* shown above contains no *error handling* and assume the **Input** menu exist on the **Menu Bar**

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

---

**Answer to Original Question**

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, show below, was tested under **macOS Catalina** with **Language & Region**  set to **English (US)** in **System Preferences** and worked for me as coded, when the **Keyboard Viewer** was opened from the **Input** menu on the **Menu Bar**.

Testing was done from **Script Editor**, as well as when used as a *shell script* from **Terminal** using a `#!/usr/bin/osascript` *shebang* and made *executable* with `chmod +x filename`.

Unfortunately, I was unable to use basic vanilla **AppleScript** to click the **Close** *button* as it is apparently not allowed with the **Keyboard Viewer** *window*, so this script makes use of a *third-party* utility named [**`cliclick`**](https://www.bluem.net/en) and was placed in `/usr/local/bin/`.

The **Keyboard Viewer** *window* can be in two different states on screen, normal *window* and minimized *window* as illustrated in the images below:

[image]

[image]

As coded it will work with both *window* states and close the *window* by ascertaining the *position* and *size* on the screen of the **Close** *button*, and if necessary the **Keyboard** *button* too, and then use `cliclick` to click the *button(s)*.

---

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "System Events"
    if (exists window "Panel" of ¬
        application process "Assistive Control") then
        
        if (exists button "Close" of window "Panel" of ¬
            application process "Assistive Control") then
            
            tell application process "Assistive Control"
                
                set closeButtonPositionSize to {position, size} of ¬
                    button "Close" of window "Panel"
                my clickButton(closeButtonPositionSize, "Close")
                
            end tell
            
        else if (exists button "Keyboard" of group 1 of window "Panel" of ¬
            application process "Assistive Control") then
            
            tell application process "Assistive Control"
                
                set keyboardButtonPositionSize to {position, size} of ¬
                    button "Keyboard" of group 1 of window "Panel"
                my clickButton(keyboardButtonPositionSize, "Keyboard")
                
                repeat until (exists button "Close" of window "Panel")
                    delay 0.01
                end repeat
                delay 0.5
                
                set closeButtonPositionSize to {position, size} of ¬
                    button "Close" of window "Panel"
                my clickButton(closeButtonPositionSize, "Close")
                
            end tell
            
        end if
    end if
end tell


to clickButton(buttonPositionSize, buttonName)
    set xyPos to item 1 of buttonPositionSize
    set xySize to item 2 of buttonPositionSize
    set addPix to (item 1 of xySize) / 4 as integer
    set xPos to (item 1 of xyPos) + addPix
    set yPos to (item 2 of xyPos) + addPix
    
    set shellClickCloseButtonCMD to ¬
        {"/usr/local/bin/cliclick -r c:", ¬
            xPos, ",", yPos} as string
    
    set shellClickKeyboardButtonCMD to ¬
        {"/usr/local/bin/cliclick -r m:", ¬
            xPos, ",", yPos, space, "w:125", ¬
            space, "c:", xPos, ",", yPos} as string
    
    if buttonName is "Close" then
        do shell script shellClickCloseButtonCMD
    else if buttonName is "Keyboard" then
        do shell script shellClickKeyboardButtonCMD
        do shell script shellClickCloseButtonCMD
    end if
end clickButton
```

Comment: I just need simple applsecript code to simple click on "show keyboard viewer" from menu bar. if it is open then click on "hide keyboard viewer" from menu bar. Nothing much. I just need the clicks on those. There is something like "A" coming in desktop inside which i have "Show keyboard viewer"  for opening and "Hide keyboard viewer" for closing.

Comment: This "A" like option is coming on the top right corner before the spotlight search. I just need to click this and then click "show keyboard viewer" for opening on screen keyboard and "hide keyboard viewer" for closing onscreen keyboard. I just need an applescript to do this.