# How to close on screen keyboard from menu bar option “A” near the spotlight search via applescript for mojave, sierra, high sierra, el capitan

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard

I got one solution for the same question previously. But i am facing problem with other mac os. Something which will work on Big Sur, Catalina, Mojave, Sierra, High Sierra and El Capitan. At least for Mojave for now.

This is solution I got from this link and it worked in Catalina and Big Sur as I told him only for Catalina and Big Sur: [How to close on screen keyboard from menu bar option "A" near the spotlight search](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/414004/how-to-close-on-screen-keyboard-from-menu-bar-option-a-near-the-spotlight-sear?noredirect=1#comment580879_414004)

Its just I am looking for something which will be working even in Mojave, Sierra, High Sierra and El Capitan.

Comment: If you need the same answer for different macOS versions please make this clear in your original question. This will be easier for future visitors to understand than having half-written questions which point to others.

Comment: Also, we are not a script writing service. There is a solution for Catalina already. Please try to understand how it works and how you need to change it for other versions of macOS.

Answer (score 1):

> At least for Mojave for now.

Presented strictly as a *proof of concept*, the *example* **AppleScript** *code* shown below was tested and worked for me without issues as is under **macOS Mojave** 10.14.6 in **Script Editor**, under the following conditions:

- In **System Preferences** > **Keyboard**>  **Keyboard**:

  - **[√] Show keyboard and emoji viewers in menu bar**
- In **System Preferences** > **Keyboard**>  **Input Source**:

  - **[√] Show Input menu in menu bar**
- In **System Preferences** > **Accessibility** > **Keyboard** > **Accessibility Keyboard**:

  - **[ ] Enable Accessibility Keyboard**
- **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility**

  - **[√] Script Editor**
- **System Preferences** > **Language & Region**:

  - **Preferred languages:**
  - **English**
  - **English (US) — Primary**
- **Keyboard Viewer** was made visible by clicking the **Show Keyboard Viewer** *menu item* of the **Input menu** on the **menu bar**.

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* hides the **Keyboard Viewer** if it's visible and the **Hide Keyboard Viewer** *menu item* exists on the **Input menu** on the **menu bar** by clicking it.

```applescript
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "SystemUIServer"
        tell menu bar 1
            if ((menu bar items whose description is "text input") exists) then
                if menu item "Hide Keyboard Viewer" of menu 1 of ¬
                    (menu bar items whose description is "text input") exists then
                    click (menu bar items whose description is "text input")
                    delay 0.2
                    click menu item "Hide Keyboard Viewer" of menu 1 of ¬
                        (menu bar items whose description is "text input")
                end if
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Thankyou so much for the solution.You are the best. Will this even work for sierra, high sierra and el capitan?

Comment: Thanks a lot it works for mojave, was also looking for sierra, high sierra and el capitan

Comment: @Ritesh Kumar, As I have previously said, **Ask Different** is not a _code_ writing service! Things can an do vary from every single _update/upgrade_ release of **OS X/macOS**, much less the conditions of what one is trying to do. Please reread my answer as I could not have been any more explicit and specific! Sorry, but I am not going to test this under every scenario you want, that's up to you to do and make changes as needed/necessary/wanted.